# Quelle est l’ordre préféré dans les expressions avec « mettre en » ?

Tags: syntaxe

Il y a beaucoup d'expressions françaises utilisant l’élément « mettre en », p.ex. :

- mettre en **relief**,
- mettre en **évidence**,
- mettre en **exergue**,
- mettre en **cause**,
- mettre en **doute**,
- mettre en **équation**,

etc.

Mais où mieux placer le complément d’objet direct ?

1. mettre ***quelque chose*** en doute, ou
2. mettre en doute ***quelque chose*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si ce complément est court on le place avant ;

- Pour **mettre** la marchandise **en évidence**, il la sortait sur le trottoir.
- Ils ont **mis** le texte **en relief** au moyen de cadres de couleur.

S'il est long il vient après ;

- Il avait **mis en évidence** un vieux modèle dont il ne voulait plus.
- Il faut **mettre en relief** tous ces éléments de texte qui sont ajoutés en tant qu'illustrations.

Ces deux principes ne sont pas, évidemment, applicables d'une façon quantitative ; le complément peut ne pas être trop long et les deux positions sont acceptables ;

- Si vous voulez **mettre** ces quantités particulières de votre problème **en équation**, il faut faire attention à ce principe.
- Si vous voulez **mettre en équation** ces quantités particulières de votre problème, il faut faire attention à ce principe.
- Pour **mettre en doute** les assertions confuses et le plus souvent hésitantes de cette personne, il suffit de vous rappeler de ceci.
- Pour **mettre** les assertions confuses et le plus souvent hésitantes de cette personne **en doute**, il suffit de se rappeler de ceci. (*lecture plus si aisée*)
- Pour **mettre** les assertions confuses et le plus souvent hésitantes de la première des personnes qui ont témoigné **en doute**, il a rappelé ceci. (*trop long, le placement « après » est nécessaire*)
- Pour **mettre en doute** les assertions confuses et le plus souvent hésitantes de la première  personne qui a témoigné, il a rappelé ceci.

Il faut savoir cependant que cela est en voie d'être changé ; une pratique courante dans les domaines de l'informatique et du journalisme consiste à placer le complément très court après ;

- Ils **mettent à  jour** le programme très souvent.

Comment: Que veulent dire *lecture plus si aisée* et  *de cette première des personne qui a témoigné* ?

Comment: @jlliagre 1: Ce que la phrase communique n'est plus si facilement assimilé, on fait les connexions entre les éléments moins rapidement, elle ne sont pas si vite reconnues (ma formulation n'est-elle pas une formulation courante pour cette idée ?) ; dans le second problème je crois que le démonstratif n'est pas un bon choix, je corrige ça.

Comment: Une pratique courante ? Tu veux dire par là qu'il y a une volonté de changement ? Sans référence c'est un peu des mots en l'air.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ce ne sont pas du tout des mots en l'air, il n'y a qu'à se servir du système d'exploitation « Windows 10 » et lire les nouvelles de Microsoft ; on a constamment des exemples de ce que j'asserte ; en particulier l'exemple que je cite est typique de maintes phrases concernant le terme « mettre à jour » ; vous ne pouvez pas vous servir de Windows 10 pour dire cela ; néanmoins, d'après ce que vous dites, cette tendance ne serait pas aussi générale que l'on puisse le croire ; il est quand même bizarre que dans ces deux domaines les utilisateurs du langage se permettent cela.

Comment: @LPH merci pour avoir rédigé ma question. Néanmoins, pourquoi remplaces les points-virgules avec virgules ? C’était correcte : https://bien-ecrire.fr/comment-bien-ecrire-une-liste-a-puces/

Comment: @MrVocabulary Après un deux-points, les éléments d'une énumération dans le texte normal (sans mise en valeur) sont séparés par des virgules ; je pense qu'il n'y a pas de raison, simplement parce que l'on met en valeur ces éléments par des puces dans le texte technique, de changer cela ; néanmoins, si vous croyez sincèrement qu'il est important d'utiliser des  points-virgules, utilisez la commande « rollback » et restituez ainsi tous les points-virgules. (la réponse à ma question, pourquoi remplacer, c'était correct)